# The minimum number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$so that two pairs will be identical.

Tags: combinatorics

There are two sets $A=\left\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_m\right\}$ and $B=\left\{b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n\right\}$ of real numbers.The minimum number of ordered pairs $(x,y),x\in A,y\in B$ that must be written,is..... so that two pairs will be identical.

---

I could not understand this question.Can someone please suggest me right way to solve it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Can you do it choosing single numbers from A?  How many numbers must be in a list so that you guarantee at least one match?  Now how many different ordered pairs are possible?

Comment: Which two pairs question says "will be identical"@Ross Millikan

Comment: The number of different ordered pairs is a step on the way to the answer. It is used the same way the number $m$ is used in the answer to the first question I asked.

Comment: Sir the answer given in the book is $mn+1$@Ross Millikan

Comment: Why this +1,i did not understand@Ross Millikan

Comment: Did you think about the first question?  If you have $m$ choices, when you choose the $m+1^{\text{st}}$ you have to have a pair.  If there are $mn$ different ordered pairs, when you list the $mn+1^{\text{st}}$ you must have a pair.  Try an example with $m=2,n=3$.  There are $2 \cdot 3=6$ different pairs.  You can then list $6$ pairs with no duplicates, but if you list $6+1=7$ you will have a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Yes sir,i understood,thank you@Ross Millikan